# Screen is black after waking up from suspend

Tags: linux, debian, nvidia-graphics-card

I am using Debian testing. When I suspend the system and wake it up again the computer wakes up but the screen is black.

I have GeForce RTX 3050 video card with Nvidia driver installed.

According to this answer [Ask Ubuntu - How can I find what video driver is in use on my system?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23238/how-can-i-find-what-video-driver-is-in-use-on-my-system), when I run

```
lspci -nnk | egrep -i --color 'vga|3d|2d' -A3 | grep 'in use'
```

I get this output: **Kernel driver in use: nvidia**.

Any idea how to solve this?